# No errors when setting an incorrect http proxy host via Java system property

Tags: java, http, proxy

Im trying to get all http requests that my Java application makes to go through a proxy. Ive set the proxy host and port via system properties

```
 System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "192.168.1.23")
 System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8081")
```

The problem I have is that the application will make http requests even if the proxy isnt available. In fact if I put in any non-valid proxy host property Java seems to ignore the proxy setting and connect directly anyway.

Id like to force all http connections to use these proxy settings and fail (via exception) if it cant connect to the proxy. Any ideas for how I can force this behaviour?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think your program is not referring to the proxy settings at all and hence no errors. I believe in addition to your proxy settings you also need to set the property 'http.proxySet' to true to indicate to the JVM that it has to use the proxy.

Comment: The "http.proxySet" property is not mentioned in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/net/properties.html ... so I think it must be an imaginary one.  Setting imaginary properties doesn't have any effect :-)

Comment: http.proxySet is an urban myth. There is no such property.